# Extend Slide Duration Of Slider Pro Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using [Slider Pro](http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/) for a auto cycling slideshow on a website. I need to extend the duration that each image of the slideshow is shown. In the [documents](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/docs/api.md#javascript-api) it mentions a property called "slideAnimationDuration" which is defaulted to a value of 700. I tried changing the value but it had no effect. There also was not much info online either. If someone could please assist me that would be wonderful!

Here is my code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#my-slider").sliderPro();
});

$("#my-slider").sliderPro({
  width: '100%',
  height: $(".header").height(),
  slideAnimationDuration: 5000,
  arrows: true,
  buttons: false,
  waitForLayers: true,
  fade: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoScaleLayers: false
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
    <div class="sp-slides">
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/rp1imhbw1s06vjv/IMG_4875.JPG" />
      </div>
      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6ffmnfh0oukrgb7/IMG_5064.JPG" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle example link so that we can check.

Comment: Yup! Here ya [go](https://jsfiddle.net/shawntoubeau/m6c9of7o/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, there's a "autoplayDelay" property that uses milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you have linked the 'slideAnimationDuration' property seems to define how long the sliding animation takes to complete. Not the interval between each slide animation.

I can't currently see anything in the documentation to change the duration the slide is displayed for. But your issue is you have simply misunderstood what a property is for. The documentation is worded a little weird in my opinion so I think that was easy to miss.

Comment: I thought so too. I just sent the developer an email hoping he can help me.